# elements cannot be displayed in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

why do the elements cannot be displayed in the document? what is the wrong?
here is code:

```js
let heading=document.createElement("header");
let logo=document.createElement("div");
let menue=document.createElement("ul");
document.heading.appendChild(logo);
document.heading.appendChild(menue);
document.body.prepend(heading);
```

Comment: Because all those elements are empty…?

Comment: Also, there's no `document.heading`, which is why the code produces runtime errors.

Comment: also `document.document.appendChild`is not a correcy syntax

Comment: Did you check inspect element to see if they have been applied? Try adding some content to them with [`innerText`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp)

Comment: Here's fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/71cLdnsq/

Comment: Maybe you doesn't append the heading anywhere. You create it, you append elements to it, but where is it in the dom?

Answer (score 0):

Bcz you are trying to append elements dynamically and there is no header in your DOM. YOur code will not work. You can tr this one

```js
let heading = document.createElement("header");
let logo = document.createElement("div");
let menue = document.createElement("ul");
heading.appendChild(logo);
heading.appendChild(menue);
document.body.prepend(heading);
```